# Ejecutar comando cmd en windows server 2008 con app web C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net, c#-8.0

Tengo una app web c# alojada en IIS en un equipo con windows server 2008, lo que hice fue tratar de ejecutar un comando en un cmd del windows server a traves de C#, pero no funciona, lo he probado de forma local en mi equipo y si funciona el comando, no se por que no se puede realizar en el equipo con windows server, este es el codigo que uso, coloque un log pero no arroja ningun error.

```html
   public partial class Reiniciar : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSiReiniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {              

                //Indicamos que deseamos inicializar el proceso cmd.exe junto a un comando de arranque. 
                //(/C, le indicamos al proceso cmd que deseamos que cuando termine la tarea asignada se cierre el proceso).
                //Para mas informacion consulte la ayuda de la consola con cmd.exe /? 
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
                // Indicamos que la salida del proceso se redireccione en un Stream
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                //Indica que el proceso no despliegue una pantalla negra (El proceso se ejecuta en background)
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                //Inicializa el proceso
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();
                //Consigue la salida de la Consola(Stream) y devuelve una cadena de texto
                string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                //Muestra en pantalla la salida del Comando
                Console.WriteLine(result);

                Log2("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log2("ERROR  " + ex.ToString());
            }
         
        }

        protected void btnNoReiniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Menu.aspx");
        }
        private void Log2(string mensaje)
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\ArchivoExcel\log_CNT.txt"))           
            {
                w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                    DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                w.WriteLine("  :");
                w.WriteLine("  :{0}", mensaje);
                w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Los permisos de usuario que estas usando para correr tu **Application Pool**, el cual esta ligado a tu aplicación en el **IIS** no tiene los suficientes permisos para correr el **CMD**.

Podrias crear un nuevo usuario, agregarlo al grupo local **IIS AppPool**, darle permisos de escritura, lectura y ejecución.
Despues ligar tu **applicacion Pool** con este nuevo usuario.

[Seguridad: Identidades de grupos de aplicaciones en IIS 7.5 y IIS 8.0](https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/Seguridad-Identidades-de-grupos-de-aplicaciones-en-IIS-75-y-IIS-80.aspx)

[IIS_IUSRS and IUSR permissions in IIS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)

Comment: Ya le di los permisos pero sigue sin hacer nada, se reinicia solo el IIS o todo el servidor?

Comment: se reinicia solo el IIS